# Solutions to linear inequalites

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A$, $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices. All entries in $A$ are known and strictly positive, and $A$ has full rank. Matrix $B$ are unknowns.

Denote

$r_i$ be the $i$-th row of $A$,

$c_j$ be the $j$-th column of $A$,

$C_i$ be the $i$-th column of $B$,

$R_j$ be the $j$-th row of $B$.

Suppose

$r_i\cdot(C_i-C_k)\geq 0$,  for all  $k$ and all  $i$.

$c_j^T\cdot(R_k-R_j)^T\geq 0$,  for all  $k$ and all  $j$.

How can we show that all ineqaulities must hold as equality and henec matrix $B$ must have all entries equal to a constant?

Thanks.

Comment: What if all entries of $B$ are equal and nonzero?

Comment: Hi, thanks for it. It is indeed a solution and I think the question should be that whether there is any non-constant solution.

Comment: The first complicated assumption means that at the diagonal of matrix $AB$ are placed the largest elements in its rows. The second complicated assumption means that at the diagonal of matrix $BA$ are placed the smallest elements in its columns.